# Java.util.Arrays NULL

Tags: java, arrays, null

so i'm working on my CS project in which we need to sort a list of DVD's by director.
it'll compile, however when i run it i'm getting a null(in java.util.Arrays)
i've called java.text.numberformat and java.util.*
is that i forgot to add anything in my imports?
thanks friends.

```
 public void addDVD(String title, String director, int year, double cost, boolean bluray)
{
    DVD newDvd = new DVD(title, director, year, cost, bluray);
    int index = Arrays.binarySearch(collection, newDvd);
    if(index >= 0) {
        System.out.println("DVD with title " + newDvd.getTitle() + " already exists.");
    }
    else {
        int index1 = -index - 1;
        collection = insertDVD(collection, newDvd, index1);
        System.out.println("DVD with title " + newDvd.getTitle() + " added.");
    }
    totalCost += cost;
}
```

Comment: can' tell from the code you've posted.  Try posting a stack trace if you have one.

Comment: My immediate presumption from the code snippet you've posted and from your description of the error is that `collection` is `null`.  Also, from a functional standpoint, I have my doubts that this particular search would work anyway since `Arrays.binarySearch` may be looking [for the actual, concrete instance](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#binarySearch-java.lang.Object:A-java.lang.Object-) rather than its properties, since `Arrays` wouldn't know to inspect them.

Comment: @Reborn:  We don't 100% know for certain what the initialization state of `collection` is, but from the error they're encountering, it's a *very* strong hunch.  More information from the OP is definitely necessary here.

Comment: @Makoto has good point :it may return null since you didn't initialized Collection

Comment: @makoto sorry, i should have stated above i initilized collectionabove that method with 
unless it didn't carry through?

   public DVDCollection()
    {
        collection = new DVD[100];
        totalCost = 0.0;
    }'

Comment: Add *all* relevant code and information to your question.  Include the stack trace of it too.